# Restart server using any other key than Break

Tags: python, django, windows, keyboard-shortcuts

I am running a `Django` server in Windows on `Google Compute Instance`. I am connecting to it using `Microsoft Remote Desktop` app on `macOS`.

The problem is whenever I want to quit the server I have to supply a `Ctrl+Break` command to the command prompt and my MacBook keyboard doesn't have a `Break` key. Even `On-Screen keyboard` doesn't have the `Break Key`.

So instead of finding ways to find the `break` key, I want to find the ways to override the requirement of it. So my question is, is there any way I can change the shortcut for killing the server to `ctrl+c` or `ctrl+z` or any other available key instead of `break` in `Django`?

Comment: The key *is* ctrl-c; did you try it? In any case, you shouldn't be using the development server in your production environment.

Comment: I tried ctrl+c which didn't do anything. It shows ctrl+break command to quit the server. I am using the development server because it's still in development.

Comment: Do you need to see the logs? As you could run it in the background and then kill its process when done?

Comment: @Splatmistro I need to manually restart it without killing the command prompt every time. I am doing it frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a very hacky thing to do, but it solves my purpose. I created a batch file with the run command and whenever I need to run the server, I just run it with the batch script.

If I open the bat file from the command prompt or if I double click on it, I can just press `ctrl+c` to close it. That saved me a lot of time and I don't even need the `break` key.